# How to declare an helper in symfony 2

Tags: symfony

I would like to use a custom helper in my application.

I created the file Myhelper.php in Bundle/Helper/Myhelper.php with

```
namespace Project\Bundle\Helper;

class Myhelper {

    public function __construct($doctrine) {

        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;

    }

    function testMyHelper () {

        return "hi";

    }

}
```

And I tried to call it in my controller:

```
$myHelper = $this->get('Myhelper');
```

But I have the following error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("You have requested a non-existent service "myhelper".")

Must I declare it in a specific config file ?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `$controller->get($id)` function it refers to a service registered by given `$id`. If you want to use this helper in a controller you need to register it as a service in `service.yml` file (or xml, php, whatever you use for service declarations)

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    app.helpers.my_helper: # the ID of the service user to get id
        class:        Project\Bundle\Helper\MyHelper
        arguments:    ['@doctrine']
```

Then you can call `$this->get('app.helpers.my_helper');` to get the service instance.

If you want to use it not in controller but also in twig, you need to inject it as a twig extension and inject your service through dependency injection:

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    app.twig_extension:
        class: AppBundle\Twig\AppExtension
        public: false
        arguments: ['@app_helpers.my_helper']
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

You can read more about this in symfony [Service container documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html) and [Twig extension documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html)

Answer (score 2):

You should see the definition of service on symfony.
(see : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html which explains precisly how to implement a service (use by the container)).

for your example :

```html
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    myhelper:
        class:        YourClass
        arguments:    [@theservicedepedents]
```

Then call it in your controller via $this->get('myhelper')

Answer (score 1):

You try to use helper as service. If you want create helper as class with static method your implementation will work. In your example you should register class as service. How works services you can read in official symfony [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html).

Answer (score 0):

I need know in which case you want to use a helper ?

Symfony is structured to never need this kind of tools. 
Maybe you have a problem in conception of project or maybe you didn't know some tools.

Comment: Finally I use it as a service, It's to populate notifications in database from any Controller