# Trouble deploying Symfony3 on a new server

Tags: php, apache, symfony, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I have used Symfony a lot in the past and haven't had many problems. I have been trying to deploy it on a different server (Ubuntu 16 w/ Apache) and am having a lot of issues.

I am getting 500 error now (https://bereanboard.com/app_dev.php). What I have tried is to go to `*.com/config.php` and `*.com/app_dev.php` to see issues (I had to temporarily comment out the section that forbids access from non localhost). I have also been checking the Apache `error.log` and Symfony's `var/logs/prod.log`.

Keep in mind it works fine on local MAMP and on my previous CentOS.

1. First, I am for the first time encountering permission problems for var/cache and var/logs. This was pretty easy to fix with commands like `chmod -R 777 var/cache`. But why did this issue come up only on this new server? Anyway, config.php on the new server is now telling me "All checks passed".
2. Second, in var/logs/prod.log I am getting all sorts of 'Can't find class, did you forget a "use" statement?' errors. Some of these are for a twig extension `AppBundle/Twig/AppExtension.php`.

Here are some Critical erros:

> request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception InvalidArgumentException:
>   "Class "AppBundle\Controller\HomeController" does not exist." at
>   /home/travis/var/cache/prod/classes.php line 4872
>   {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Class
>   \"AppBundle\Controller\HomeController\" does not exist. at
>   /home/travis/var/cache/prod/classes.php:4872)"} []

and

> php.CRITICAL: Class 'AppBundle\Twig\AppExtension' not found
>   {"exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError(code: 0):
>   Class 'AppBundle\Twig\AppExtension' not found at
>   /home/travis/var/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer.php:2881)"} []
>   [2017-01-19 06:35:03] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: "Attempted
>   to load class "AppExtension" from namespace "AppBundle\Twig". Did you
>   forget a "use" statement for another namespace?" at
>   /home/travis/var/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer.php line 2881
>   {"exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException(code:
>   0): Attempted to load class \"AppExtension\" from namespace
>   \"AppBundle\Twig\".\nDid you forget a \"use\" statement for another
>   namespace? at
>   /home/travis/var/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer.php:2881)"} []
>   [2017-01-19 06:35:03] request.CRITICAL: Exception thrown when handling
>   an exception
>   (Symfony\Component\Cache\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Cache
>   directory is not writable
>   (/home/travis/var/cache/prod/pools/CtBqbs+VrF) at
>   /home/travis/var/cache/prod/classes.php line 1194)
>   {"exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\Cache\Exception\InvalidArgumentException(code:
>   0): Cache directory is not writable
>   (/home/travis/var/cache/prod/pools/CtBqbs+VrF) at
>   /home/travis/var/cache/prod/classes.php:1194)"} []

Also, it's worth mentioning that that a fresh, empty project made from the command `symfony new project` *does* work.

*EDIT
I have consulted [these Symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html). I have tried every way of clearing cache that I could find.

*EDIT
Here is services.yml

```
services:
    app.twig_extension:
        class: AppBundle\Twig\AppExtension
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", "@security.token_storage"]
        public: false
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

Comment: Did you clean the production cache ?

Comment: yes, `with php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug` and also by just deleting the cache folder. both ways have worked for me previously

Comment: Did you rebuild your autoload file too ? `php composer.phar dump-autoload`

Comment: I just did it and it didn't change anything. Same errors.

Comment: Are you using some Helpers with Twig ? If yes, try to check your services.yml http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36421158/how-to-declare-an-helper-in-symfony-2

Comment: @AlexandreT check my edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133522/discussion-between-alexandre-t-and-billyhafiz).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is an access problem for your web server.

Check user which launching apache on Centos by

```
# egrep -i '^user|^group' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

It should return `apache`

Then give the good privilege to `/home/travis` directory:

- Option 1: You could have a look on [Stack Echange / AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26848/permissions-issue-how-can-apache-access-files-in-my-home-directory) and adapt it with `apache` user instead of `www-data`
- Option 2: With first option, if you've created a folder, Apache cannot write to it. This can be "fixed" by setting umask 0007 and adding yourself (travis) to the Apache group, so that newly created files and folders are writeable by the group.

Option 2 is better if ou have enough privileges to change mask.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear cache :

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

and set files permissions :

```
chmod -R 777 var/cache
chmod -R 777 var/logs
chmod -R 777 var/sessions
```

hope this help you.

Answer (score -1):

I had faced the same problem before once. You will have to complete remove the vendor folder

> rm -R vendor/

and freshly install all the dependencies again.

> php composer.phar install

This will resolve the issue.